# Display LedgerDetails MonthlyWise from TallyErp 9 using xml tag

Tags: xml, rest, soap, tally

I am fetching ledger vouchers from tally erp9. I am able to get details monthly wise. Now I require to fetch monthly wise ledger summary like this
[image]

Currently my code for getting ledger vouchers is this:

```
<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8> 
  <ENVELOPE>
  <HEADER>
  <TALLYREQUEST>Export Data</TALLYREQUEST>
  </HEADER>
  <BODY>
  <EXPORTDATA>
  <REQUESTDESC>
  <REPORTNAME>Ledger Vouchers</REPORTNAME>
  <STATICVARIABLES>
  <SVCURRENTCOMPANY>Prakash Electrical Enterprises (17-18)</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
  <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
  <SHOWRUNBALANCE>Yes</SHOWRUNBALANCE>
  <SVFROMDATE>1-Apr-2017</SVFROMDATE>
  <SVTODATE>`+ lastDate + `</SVTODATE>
  <LEDGERNAME>`+ ledgerName + `</LEDGERNAME>
  </STATICVARIABLES>
  </REQUESTDESC>
  </EXPORTDATA>
  </BODY>
  </ENVELOPE></xml>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML request to fetch Ledger Monthly summary for a specific ledger from Tally ERP 9.

```
<ENVELOPE>
  <HEADER>
    <TALLYREQUEST>Export Data</TALLYREQUEST>
  </HEADER>
  <BODY>
    <EXPORTDATA>
      <REQUESTDESC>
        <STATICVARIABLES>

          <!--Specify the Report FORMAT here-->
          <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>

          <!-- Show Opening balances -->
          <DSPSHOWOPENING>Yes</DSPSHOWOPENING>

          <!-- Show Dr/Cr totals or only NET balance of Dr/Cr -->
          <DSPSHOWNETT>No</DSPSHOWNETT>
          <DSPSHOWTRANS>Yes</DSPSHOWTRANS>

          <!-- Month,3 Month, 6 Month, 12 Month-->
          <!-- Or specify Day for Daily breakup report-->
          <SVPERIODICITY>Month</SVPERIODICITY>

          <!-- Required for Monthly Summary Report-->
          <DSPSHOWMONTHLY>Yes</DSPSHOWMONTHLY>
          <DSPSHOWALLACCOUNTS>Yes</DSPSHOWALLACCOUNTS>

          <!--Specify the Period here. -->
          <SVFROMDATE>20170401</SVFROMDATE>
          <SVTODATE>20180331</SVTODATE>

          <!-- Specify the LedgerName here -->
          <LEDGERNAME>ABC</LEDGERNAME>
        </STATICVARIABLES>

        <!-- Report Name -->
        <REPORTNAME>Ledger Monthly Summary</REPORTNAME>
      </REQUESTDESC>
    </EXPORTDATA>
  </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

Remarks:

1. Specify the ledger name in the tag **LEDGERNAME**
2. Use the **SVPERIODICITY** tag for grouping on monthly, quarterly etc

https://www.rtslink.com